# Localhost (wordpress) works, but static IP and domain name does not show anything

Tags: apache2, wordpress, localhost, static-ip

I am a first-timer with this stuff. I have a new Ubuntu server. I have PostFix and SSH working.

I have installed Wordpress (Lamp stack, apache2, and MariaDB). I also installed NextCloud and uninstalled it again.

Now, Localhost shows my wordpress site just fine. But my static IP and domain name do not.

When I go to my static IP:

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at [Static ip here].
```

When I go to my domain name:

```
Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

We can’t connect to the server at [domain name].
```

It is always hard to know what data to present here. But from other posts (I have tried to follow them but to no success) I see some stuff, I'll add it, but please ask if you need more.

iptables -L -n | grep 80

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       [computername]

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

netstat -ltnp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1013/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      713/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      913/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1091/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2251/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1048/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      913/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1091/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1048/apache2
```

ufw status verbose

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
25/tcp (Postfix)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
465/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
25/tcp (Postfix (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
465/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

lsof -i :80

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 1048     root    4u  IPv6  31553      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 4128 www-data    4u  IPv6  31553      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 4129 www-data    4u  IPv6  31553      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 4130 www-data    4u  IPv6  31553      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 4131 www-data    4u  IPv6  31553      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 4132 www-data    4u  IPv6  31553      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2 4134 www-data    4u  IPv6  31553      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

a2dissite command only shows my own domain.

my config for the domain (is in sites-enabled)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName [domain name]
  ServerAlias www.[domain name]
  ServerAdmin [my mail]
  DocumentRoot /var/www/[domain name]
    
  <Directory "/var/www/[domain name]">
       Options FollowSymlinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
  </Directory>

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
</VirtualHost>
```

I feel I have tried many things now, but I cannot seem to find the right post to guide me to the answer.

One final thing is that my domain name is .dk, I do not know if that changes anything, but now you know.

I hope you can.

Comment: If you installed WordPress via the setup pages using http://localhost, then the issue will be in WordPress. You'll have to reconfigure some of the meta data to use your proper domain rather than localhost.

Comment: I did not. WordPress uses my domain. Which also means I cannot press any links on the locahost-page.

Answer (score 0):

The ISP had reset the router settings (apparently does that once a year on default), so my static IP had changed.